# Control like debug Object list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I want to create a WPF control which looks like control which appears while we debug .NET code. I.e. control like the window which shows all the property/value and have top and bottom arrow, clicking on which list scrolls up/down. (I am looking for control which have Scroll bar in this style).

To be more specific, I want to make a control like a Panel in which I can display controls/text and which have sroll button in middle like it appears in debug window as shown in Image link.

Link is having sample of control I am trying to make.

http://www.use.com/supersize.pl?set=11a2085f136b99d6869c

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Those buttons with the little triangles on them are standard wpf  repeat buttons that have been styled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the WPF Visualizer that comes with Visual Studio. You can access it in debug mode once execution has hit a break point. It displays every property and value for every item in the visual tree. You can find out more from the [How to: Use the WPF Tree Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409789.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: I think he wants to deploy one in an app.

Comment: Thanks for response. 
But I am looking to make control like this, in which I can put text/control inside and which have scroll in middle.

Answer (score 0):

The control you wanted probably like this

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RepeatButton>Up</RepeatButton>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="sv" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Rectangle Height="700" Fill="Black"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2">Down</RepeatButton>

    </Grid>
```

also you should control scrollview in codebehind via click eventhandler of RepeatButton.